# Bolts failed to compile when linked against App extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, bolts-framework

I'm using in my project the latest **Facebook** **iOS** SDK:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.19.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.19.0'
```

Bolts is a **FBSDKCoreKit** dependency. And this is my problem: actual version of **FBSDKCoreKit** needs at least **Bolts 1.7**:

```
`Bolts (~> 1.7)` required by `FBSDKCoreKit (4.19.0)`
```

But in th**e BFAppLinkNavigation.m** there are multiple reference like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appLinkAppURL]
```

I have to link **FBSDKCoreKit** against a today extension, and this is now impossible because all the **Bolts** version from **1.7** to the latest **1.8.4**, references to `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, so it's impossible for me to build the project correctly:

```
~project/Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLinkNavigation.m:114:36: 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.
```

Anyone have even a dirty solution to fix that?